# How can I make this not start until a valid answer in a popup box

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I want to make this not begin to load until a prompt box is answered with a valid answer. and only popup once a month, is this possible? or do I need anything else besides JS and HTML?

```
<script language="javascript">
 function buildBar(id, callback) {
     var currentAdb = 0;
     var imgCtb = 150;

     function cycleb() {
         var output = '';
         for (var i = 0; i < imgCtb; i++) {
             output += i > currentAdb ? '&nbsp;' : '/';
         }
         output += '';
         document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = output;
         ++currentAdb;
         if (currentAdb == imgCtb) {
             window.clearInterval(myInterval);
             if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                 callback();
             }
         }
         else{
             window.setTimeout(cycleb,10+Math.random()*225);
         }


     }
     var myInterval = window.setTimeout(cycleb, 100);
 }

 function callback1() {
     buildBar('adLinkb2', callback2);
 }

 function callback2() {
     //window.location... stuff here
     window.location = "https://findretros.com/rankings/vote/NabboHotel";
 }

 buildBar('adLinkb', callback1);
 </script>
 <div id="adLinkb" style="border: 1px solid black;width:452;background-color:black;border-color:white"></div>
<div id="adLinkb2" style="border: 1px solid black;width:452;background-color:black;border-color:white"></div>
```

Comment: Will it pop up at the same time every month? Or would it pop-up one month after the user accessed the page and provided a valid answer?

Comment: Anything is possible ;)
what did you try out to see if it would work and why were the results not satisfactory for you? If you had a magic wand and could make code work any way you wanted, what would you write? and which bits are the bits that don't actually work when you try that?

Comment: @Kenny Johnson Its a game page and every month it will popup with a prompt box saying enter a rule before continuing! that way I can make sure they understand the rules

Comment: and if possible you can't enter the same one next month. IDK if its possible though

Comment: As Taryn East said, "Anything is possible".  It just depends on how much work you want to put into it. My answer provided a good starting point. I think you'll be able to work out how to make it different each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using prompt(), then checking the value the user entered in the prompt.

```js
function bar(){
 document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="You answered the question correctly!"  
}
function foo(){
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="You didn't answer the question correctly."
}

var answer = prompt("Enter Test123","");
if(answer == "Test123"){
   bar(); 
}
if(answer != "Test123"){
    foo();
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

As for running it once a month... If you want it to run on the first day of every month, you could use getDate() and call a function if the result was 1 (or whatever day you want to use).  If you need to prompt the user one month after they provided the answer, then you'll need to use a server side script and a database (such as PHP + MySQL).

If the user has several strings they could enter (such as Test123, Sample456, etc) and they can't enter the same one two months in a row, you will need to use a database such as MySQL to store the results. Then you'll need to compare the answer each month to the last month's answer.